# complex scrolling - how to implement it correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll

I faced such a scrolling problem: At the bottom of the page there is a news block with pagination and page reload. Above is the standard menu. How to correctly implement: if a user in ons pagination clicks on another page, he remains in the same scrolling (i.e. at the bottom of the page). I did it like this:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {
            sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
                $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
            }
        });


</script>
```

But if the user who is at the bottom of the page clicks on any menu item at the top, he should, after loading, be on a new page at the top of the page, but of course he rolls down with this script. I put the event onclick Top, but how to do it only after reloading on a new page? Maybe my decision is wrong and there are other options. Thanks for any help !!